# How to add an attribute to an xsd:any element

Tags: xml, xsd, any

How do you add an attribute to an xsd:any element?  For example, given the following:

```
<xsd:element name="requests">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any namespace="http://xxx.yyy.com" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

How do you add  as an attribute to any so that the following xml can be validated against the schema without errors:

```
<requests>
    <operation count="1">
<requests>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xsd:any cannot include any attribute declarations, because it essentially allows any element that is defined within the namespace "http://xxx.yyy.com" to be declared within the sequence. If you are not using a separate XSD to validate that namespace, then you can simply use the following in place of xsd:any:

```
<xsd:element name="operation">
   <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="count" type="nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Otherwise, you will want to declare a namespace prefix for "http://xxx.yyy.com" at the top of your XSD and refer to the element within that schema instead of xsd:any. So, if the schema for "http://xxx.yyy.com" includes the following declaration:

```
<xsd:complexType name="operationType">
   <xsd:attribute name="count" type="nonNegativeInteger" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Then you could reference this type in your XSD:

```
<xsd:element name="requests">           
   <xsd:complexType>           
      <xsd:sequence>           
         <xsd:element type="optype:operationType"/>           
      </xsd:sequence>           
   </xsd:complexType>           
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Actually, I'm creating a heartbeat wsdl operation which will contain counts for all operations for an end-point. The heartbeat operation will be used in all web services and needs to be generic in nature so it doesn't have to be tweaked each time.

Comment: In the example, <requests> <operation count="1"> <requests> operation will end up being 1 or more web service operations. So, it doesn't seem I should be specifying a namespace as part of any since that would use the definition for that element and that is not what I'm trying to accomplish. And, if there is no way to add an attribute to an any element, then I guess the attribute(s) will need to be any children.

Comment: Unfortunately, using a child element for count won't work either, because you can't have nested xsd:any elements. The only child element you can place under xsd:any is xsd:annotation

Comment: Yes, I just found that out.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you want to allow any element as a child so long as it has a count attribute, then you can't do that in XSD 1.0. You can do it in XSD 1.1 (currently supported in Saxon and Xerces) with an assertion:

```
<xs:assert test="every $x in * satisfies (exists($x/@count) and $x/@count castable to xs:integer)"/>
```